# I did not get the data in APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

In my APIView:

```
data = {
    "user":user_dict,  # the user_dict have data.
    "account":account_dict  # the account_dict have data too.
      }

serializer = UserInfoSerializer(data=data)
is_valid = serializer.is_valid()  # the `is_valid` is True

return Response(data=serializer.validated_data, status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

But when I access this APIView, I get nothing.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

The `UserInfoSerializer` code is bellow:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(Serializer):
    user = serializers.DictField(read_only=True)
    account = serializers.DictField(read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is because of the semantics of how the serializer.DictField is supposed to be used. when you create a dict field, you need to tell the serializer what the types of the values in the dictionary are. For example, lets say that "user" is a dictionary like this: `{"user1": "bob", "user2": "alice"}`. Then you need to tell the serializer the child values are strings, or a CharField as such:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(Serializer):
    user = serializers.DictField(read_only=True, child=serializers.CharField())
```

If account is `{"account1": 1, "account2": 2}`, then you would do this:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(Serializer):
    user = serializers.DictField(read_only=True, child=serializers.CharField())
    account = serializers.DictField(read_only=True, child=serializers.IntegerField())
```

I tested this locally and this seemed to fix the issue. You can read more about how to use the DictField in [djangos docs here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield).

If your data does not have values that are consistently a single type, I would recommend using the JSONField which you can read about [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield). It would look like this:

```
class UserInfoSerializer(Serializer):
    user = serializers.JSONField()
    account = serializers.JSONField()
```

Good luck!

Comment: How about there are `CharField` and `IntegerField` in a DictField?

Comment: If your fields are inconsistent, I would recommend using a JSONField(): http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#jsonfield. I edited the answer to reflect JSON Field

Comment: Is it the same behavior where it returns an empty object?

Comment: Yeah. the same, I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Just this: `class UserInfoSerializer(Serializer):
    user = serializers.JSONField()
    account = serializers.JSONField()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163301/discussion-between-rohan-varma-and-qg-java-17137).